# CLLocation manager Time Out problem

Tags: iphone

I found current location using (CLLocationManager startUpdatingLocation) this method. How long it takes to find current location ?(In minutes).

Because i want to set time out for CLLocationManger classes to stop updatinglocation.

Can anyone help me ? Thanks in advance.......

My location manager desiredAccuracy should be kCLLocationAccuracyBest and distancefilter should be kCLDistanceFilterNone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you started your stopwatch at moment when you entered into tunnel, you will get your gps coordinates immediately after you exit the tunnel.